# Jquery is change String value

Tags: php, javascript, html

the Input Box has a value `Hanako&#60;`.
after I call the jquery to get value, It alert `Hanako<`. 
I want to alert `Hanako&#60;`

Jquery code:

```
var chk_val_2 = $('#txt_rename' + chk_check).val();
alert (chk_val_2);
```

Please Help me.

Comment: jQuery is changing the order of `*` and `<`? I doubt it.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo please

Answer (score 1):

Is your HTML like this:

```
<input id="txt_rename123" type="text" value="Hanako&#60;">
```

HTML replaces entities in attribute values, so if you want a literal `&` you have to write:

```
<input id="txt_rename123" type="text" value="Hanako&amp;#60;">
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rd5eu/)

Comment: I have a question. My database is store this string which is "Hanako&amp;#60;". True or Not?

Comment: Yes. If you always want to show entities explicitly, you have to store them literally.